# Shell script to set password for samba user

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, scripting, samba

I would like to set a password for setting up `samba` share directory using a shell script. I wrote the following script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

pass=123456
(echo "$pass"; echo "$pass") | smbpasswd -s -a $(whoami)
```

This prints the following:

```
When run by root:
    smbpasswd [options] [username]
otherwise:
    smbpasswd [options]

options:
  -L                   local mode (must be first option)
  -h                   print this usage message
  -s                   use stdin for password prompt
  -c smb.conf file     Use the given path to the smb.conf file
  -D LEVEL             debug level
  -r MACHINE           remote machine
  -U USER              remote username
extra options when run by root or in local mode:
  -a                   add user
  -d                   disable user
  -e                   enable user
  -i                   interdomain trust account
  -m                   machine trust account
  -n                   set no password
  -W                   use stdin ldap admin password
  -w PASSWORD          ldap admin password
  -x                   delete user
  -R ORDER             name resolve order
```

As it points out, I was not running it as root, when I run it as root, i.e., `sudo ./test.sh`, it runs fine. But the catch is, it adds `root` instead of `noobuser`, which is my logged in user.

How can I add `noobuser` by doing something similar (I have a feeling I'm missing something here)?

Comment: why not replace `$(whoami)` by `$(echo noobuser)` ?

Comment: I would like to make it a generic script, which can be run in other systems as well. The username there could be anything.

Answer (score 5):

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

pass=123456

if [ -z "$SUDO_USER" ]; then
    echo "This script is only allowed to run from sudo";
    exit -1;
fi

(echo "$pass"; echo "$pass") | smbpasswd -s -a "$SUDO_USER"
```

invocation:

```
sudo ./test.sh
```

Comment: I like this answer, but would like to know if it possible without passing an argument.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit:
It depends. You can use `logname` or `who am i` as @Sagar stated, but it will work only if the user you want to be used for script has been the very first one to log in to shell within chain logins. I. e. you cannot login as root, then sudo to noobuser and then use this method.

Comment: Okay. I was not aware of that. I tried replacing with both `logname` and `who am i` in @Sagar's answer. But, that didn't help as well. The problem here starts with running the script as `sudo`. Is there a way to cheat the system to believing it is still `noobuser` and not `root` while using `sudo`?

Comment: Assuming that you will always run this from sudo, you can use $SUDO_USER enviroment variable

I've made proper corrections to the answer.

Comment: `$SUDO_USER`, `$USER` are all environment variables that can be changed right? I prefer not to use them. That's why I was using `whoami`.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit: That's interesting. Could you provide an example of changing $SUDO_USER variable if you do not have rights to modify test.sh file?

Comment: Belatedly, and for future readers, the `SUDO_USER` variable is created and managed by the `sudo` tool itself. Provided you understand this it can be perfectly safe to reference within a `sudo`-driven script

Answer (score 4):

This is a fragment of how i automate `smbpasswd -a` via bash script, works like charm.

```
username="bob"

pass="secret"

echo -e "$pass\n$pass" | smbpasswd -a -s $username
```

this one is extended, it inserts the current username for you. (without awk it's shorter & cleaner)

```
pass="secret"

echo -e "$pass\n$pass" | smbpasswd -a -s $(id -un)
```

.

**find more details below:**

.

## echo -e

> The -e option is used to enable echo's interpretation of additional
> instances of the newline character as well as the interpretation of
> other special characters, such as a horizontal tab, which is
> represented by \t.

## pipe symbol “|”

> In Unix-like computer operating systems, a pipeline is a mechanism for inter-process communication using message passing.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/756158/what-does-the-linux-pipe-symbol-do
>
> **credit goes to: [LawrenceC](https://superuser.com/users/51705/lawrencec), Wikipedia**

## smbpasswd -s

> The -s option causes smbpasswd to be silent (i.e. not issue prompts)
> and to read its old and new passwords from standard input, rather than
> from /dev/tty (like the passwd(1) program does). This option is to aid
> people writing scripts to drive smbpasswd

## id -u -n

> `id` displays the system identifications of a specified user.
>
> outputs: `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) grupy=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel)`
>
> **Display a name instead of a UID/GID**
>
> By default, id command displays number for the -G, -g and -u options. You can force id
> command to display the name of the UID or GID instead of the number
> for the -G, -g and -u options by passing the -n option as follows:
>
> ```
> id -ng {UserNameHere}
> id -nu {UserNameHere}
> id -nG {UserNameHere}
> id -nG vivek
> ```
>
> read more about `id`: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-id-command-examples-usage-syntax/
>
> **Credit goes to: [Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23931327) (solution), [Vivek Gite](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-id-command-examples-usage-syntax/) (deep infos)**
>
> a little hint in case of problems **(Credit to: [Paul](https://superuser.com/a/343163/1169381))**: https://superuser.com/a/343163/1169381

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to pass argument to script then you may try this

```
#!/bin/bash

pass=123456
echo $pass
echo $pass | smbpasswd -s -a $(who am i | awk '{print $1}')
```

and then invoke the script.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me - `echo $pass | smbpasswd -s -a $(whoami | awk '{print $1}')` or `echo $pass | smbpasswd -s -a $(who am i | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: what was the stdout after executing this ?

Comment: The same I had pasted in my question!

Answer (score 0):

I'm create file name smb.sh, content like this

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /home/user_data/$1

#add owner
chown -R $1 /home/user_data/$1
#owner only 
chmod -R 700 /home/user_data/$1


user=$1
pass=$2

#sleep 3
smbpasswd -a $user<<EOF
$pass
$pass
EOF
```

and you can send params to smb.sh like this

```bsh
./smb.sh myusername  mypassword
```

like simple, you can use file smb.sh with PHP language, use PHP exec function

Comment: Well, I guess that it’s fairly obvious that this needs to be run as root, but you should say so anyway. Is a here document better than `echo |`? If so, how? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.